# buttons are not responsive. They are not updated when screen size changes

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I expect the buttons updated when the scree size changes. The two buttons are placed on an `img` and wrapped with links. Any help is appreciated. 
template is below:

```
    <div class="img">
        <img src="topimage.jpg"
        <a href="#" ><button class="left-button">left</button></a>
        <a href="#" ><button class="right-button">right</button></a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.left-button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8%;
    top: 19%;
    font-size: 115%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.8em;
}
.right-button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 37%;
    top: 19%;
    font-size: 115%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.8em;
}
.img {
     width: 100%;
     display:inline-block;
     position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: <img src="topimage.jpg"/> //Your html isinvalid - you need to close your img tag.

Comment: You should show what you want to achieve and what's not working.

Comment: with some javascript you can get your window dimensions and update your buttons dimensions (you can call the function in load so each time you open your window the buttons dimensions will be updated depending on your window size)`<script>
function updatedimensions() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    x = document.getElementById("yourbutton");
    //update your dimensions
}
</script>`

Comment: @Doodlebunch, hi, I want the two buttons placed in the right relative position according to the img. But the position is messed up when the screen size is smaller.

Comment: @Axess Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc1a6y5g/ Looks kinda good to me, can you point out whats wrong?

Comment: @Doodlebunch, first, the two buttons are on the img, second, i would like the position of the two buttons keep same according to the img, when the screen size changes and the img size changes, the buttons changes too, but keep the relative positions. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are not responsive to the `img`. You need to set a width on your buttons. Like:

```
.left-button { 
    width:30%;
    //your css
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4scr9hn/)**

Comment: Hi Frederik, since I specified font-size, do I still need width? I tried to add width, it didn't work.

Comment: Hey, the font-size is not responsive to the window width. The % on the font size are related  to the font size of the parent. Example: Your parent has a font size of 10px, so with 130% font size on your buttons, your buttons have a font size of 13px.

Comment: Added a working fiddle. Can you tell me what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Frederik, thanks for helping! I expect both the size and the position of the two buttons are relatively stable according to the img. Now they move around.

Comment: Could you share a fiddle for me?